# How do you dynamically Invoke a constructor of an object without knowing all of the parameters?

Tags: c#, dynamic, metaprogramming

Here is what I have so far:

```
var constructor = typeof (ParentModel).GetConstructor(FieldInformationTypes);
var model = (ParentModel)constructor.Invoke(Values.Values.ToArray());
return model;
```

and FieldInformationTypes (which is in the superclass of the class having the above code)

```
protected Type[] FieldInfoTypes;
public Type[] FieldInformationTypes
{
    get
    {
        if (FieldInfoTypes == null) return FieldInfoTypes;

        var memberTypes = (
            from fieldInfo in FieldInformation
            select fieldInfo.MemberType).ToArray();

        FieldInfoTypes = (
            from memberType in memberTypes
            select memberType.GetType()).ToArray();

        return FieldInfoTypes;
    }
}

protected FieldInfo[] FieldInfos;
public FieldInfo[] FieldInformation
{
    get
    {
        // don't GetFields all the time
        if (FieldInfos != null) return FieldInfos;

        FieldInfos = typeof(T).GetFields(
            BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            BindingFlags.Instance);

        return FieldInfos;
    }
}
```

Where `T` is the class with the constructor I'm trying to dynamically create.

`Values` is just a dictionary of `strings` to `objects`, where the strings are the parameter field names, and values can be whatever.

I know that with named parameters, the `ParentModel` can be created like this:

```
new ParentModel(
    children: _children,
    isResponsible: _isResponsible);
```

Or via this technique:

```
new ParentModel()
{
    Children = _children,
    IsResponsible = _isResponsible
};
```

Both of those techniques for invoking a method (in my case, the constructor) look an awful lot like a hash / dictionary. So, I feel like it should be possible to dynamically invoke methods via a dictionary. My question is: how?

Ideally, I'd like to just be able to invoke a method by doing something like this:

```
new MyObject(myDictionaryOfParameters.ToNamedParameter());
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

What about such extension method for the ConstructorInfo returned by GetConstructor():

```
    public static object Invoke(this ConstructorInfo constructor, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        List<object> parameterValues = new List<object>();
        foreach(var parameterInfo in constructor.GetParameters())
        {
            if (parameters.ContainsKey(parameterInfo.Name))
                parameterValues.Add(parameters[parameterInfo.Name]);
            else
                parameterValues.Add(null);
        }
        return constructor.Invoke(parameterValues.ToArray());
    }
```

then you could make such call:

```
var constructor = typeof (ParentModel).GetConstructor(FieldInformationTypes);
var model = (ParentModel)constructor.Invoke(Values);
return model;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in your first example `Values` is your `Dictionary<string, object>` what you have won't work.  `Dictionaries` do not preserve order so you can't be sure that the values you get our of the dictionary match the parameters on the constructor.  You can instead use the [`GetParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) method to line up your parameters:

```
var constructor = typeof (ParentModel).GetConstructor(FieldInformationTypes);
var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();
var model = (ParentModel)constructor.Invoke(parameters.Select(p => Values[p.Name]).ToArray());
return model;
```

Using named parameters doesn't pass the parameters as a dictionary.  The compiler will re-write the call to a normal method call.  Also your second example is passing no parameters to the constructor.

```
new ParentModel()
{
    Children = _children,
    IsResponsible = _isResponsible
};
```

This calls the default constructor and the sets the `Children` and `IsResponsible` properties.  It is just syntactic sugar for this:

```
var model new ParentModel();
model.Children = _children;
model.IsResponsible = _isResponsible;
```